# Compiling Rstudio Server on el-capitan

Tags: installation, rstudio, rstudio-server

I used to run a rstudio server on my mac about a year ago. However, I didnt use it much so I deleted it. However, now I need to set it up again. In the meantime, I´ve changed to el capitan and the instructions on https://iangow.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/rstudio-server-on-mac-os-x/ is failing. First I was having trouble caompiling due to OpenSSL and el capitan. However, I believe that was taken care of by [[Rstudio server installation el capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379115/rstudio-server-installation-el-capitan][1]). Now, after `sudo make install` it compiles but in the end it throws an error that I cannot decipher. Anye ideas what is wrong here?

EDIT 1- as per the suggestion to remove suggested I removed the rstudio directory and did a clean install. However- I get the same error in the end.

```
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [src/cpp/session/rsession] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2




[ 92%] Linking CXX executable rsession
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionModuleContext.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionRUtil.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionUserSettings.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionAuthoring.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionBreakpoints.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionCodeSearch.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionUserCommands.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionConsole.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionDependencies.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionDiagnostics.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionDirty.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionErrors.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionFiles.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionFilesQuotas.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionGit.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionHelp.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionHTMLPreview.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionLimits.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionMarkers.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionPackages.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionPackrat.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionPlots.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionRCompletions.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionRHooks.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionRParser.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionRSConnect.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionShinyViewer.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionSource.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionSpelling.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionSVN.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionWorkbench.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/build/SessionBuild.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/build/SessionBuildEnvironment.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/clang/RCompilationDatabase.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/clang/SessionClang.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/data/DataViewer.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/environment/EnvironmentMonitor.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/environment/EnvironmentUtils.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/environment/SessionEnvironment.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/presentation/SessionPresentation.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/presentation/PresentationLog.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/presentation/SlideRequestHandler.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/presentation/Tutorial.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/presentation/TutorialInstaller.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/rmarkdown/SessionRMarkdown.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/shiny/SessionShiny.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/tex/SessionCompilePdf.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/tex/SessionRnwWeave.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/tex/SessionTexUtils.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/viewer/SessionViewer.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/projects/SessionProjects.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/projects/SessionProjectContext.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RExec.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RFunctionHook.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RJsonRpc.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(ROptions.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RRoutines.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RSexp.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RSourceManager.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RUtil.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RClientMetrics.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RConsoleActions.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RSearchPath.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RSessionState.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RSession.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RGraphicsDevice.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RGraphicsPlot.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RGraphicsPlotManipulator.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RGraphicsPlotManipulatorManager.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RGraphicsPlotManager.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RGraphicsUtils.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(RShadowPngGraphicsHandler.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol _R_running_as_main_program in:
    CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionMain.cpp.o
    ../r/librstudio-r.a(REmbeddedPosix.cpp.o)
ld: 73 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/cpp/session/rsession] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the CMake cache, or destroying the build folder and recreating it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after upgrading my OS X on my Mac. Note that my Macbook already had Homebrew.

Below is what I did to install RStudio Server:

1. Install the new version of Xcode
2. `brew reinstall gcc`
3. `brew install rstudio-server`